# Is it a good idea to instantiate an inline stream(reader/writer) variable?

Tags: vb.net, garbage-collection, streamreader

I am working on reducing resource usage across my client's system. One of the tasks is to ensure that any resources are properly closed and disposed of.

I know how to make use of `try-catch-finally` and `using` blocks, but I am unsure as to how the compiler handles a inline instance of a disposable variable, such as a `StreamReader`.

Below is how I am used to resolving the task:

```
Using streamRdr As New StreamReader(memStream)
    Dim test As String = streamRdr.ReadToEnd()
    'More code
End Using
```

And here is an example of an inline instance:

```
Dim test As String = New StreamReader(memStream).ReadToEnd()
```

I would like to know if the compiler properly disposes of the `StreamReader` just like a `using` block, or it relies on Garbage Collection to handle the disposal of the resource?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If the compiler could do that, there would be no need to have `Using` blocks.

Comment: In order to dispose an object, you need to call its `Dispose` method.  The `End Using` line of a `Using` block is an implicit call to the `Dispose` method of the object(s) created by the `Using` statement, so the compiler adds explicit calls. In your second code snippet, there is no call to `Dispose`, either implicit or explicit, so the object will not be disposed but rather hang around until it is finalised by the GC.

Comment: You can very this yourself *using* the memory profiler. You'll clearly see that if you don't dispose of the disposable objects you create, handles included, the memory usage of your application will grow constantly. You could just try to paint something on a Control and never dispose of the Brushes, Pens, Fonts etc. you create and then counter-test it disposing of those objects in-place. You'll see what happens and the actual difference in behaviour.

Comment: So we should always created an instance variable for classes that have a Dispose method so a using block can be used. Yes?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. That's all I needed to know. @Mary From what I gathered, if any class uses unmanaged resources, it requires a Using or Try-Catch-Finally to free up resources more efficiently.